# Given a matrix factored into a product, how do you determine the determinant?

Tags: matrices, determinant

I'm preseneted with the question:

> Suppose that a 3x3 matrix A factors into the product of the two matrices below:

\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
 I21 & 1 & 0 \\
I32 & I32 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}
\begin{matrix}
        U11 & U12 & U13 \\
        0 & U22 & U23 \\
        0 & 0 & U33 \\
        \end{matrix}

> Determine the value of det(A)

I'm very confused on how to procede with this problem. If someone could explain the method for solving such a problem, that'd be awesome.

Comment: could you please let me know what formula for determinant are you using??.. That might help you to tell directly what is determinant of an upper/lower triangular matrix...

Comment: I... don't know what formula to use. I didn't even know how to start this question. The det(AB)=detA detB hint helped. Discovering the determinant of a triangular matrix was key...

Comment: No, No.. Do you know any formula to calculate determinant of a given matrix??? while defining determinant, you will be given some formula to calculate that... do you remember what it is??

Comment: The thing where you multiply the top row by sub matrices until you get to 2x2 matrices and can calculate each using a11*a22-a12*a21 and add them all together? I know I could have done that. But I knew there had to be a faster way - the upper/lower triangular matrices ment something. I just didn't know what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic relevant fact is that $\det (AB) = \det A \det B$.

The determinant of a triangular matrix is just the product of the diagonal elements. This is easy to compute from the definition (only the identity permutation needs to be considered).

The answer is:

> $U_{11} U_{22} U_{33}$

Comment: How'd you get the answer to only appear when you scroll over it? That's cool and let me work out the problem before looking at the answer...

Comment: Use '>!'. In general, you can edit an answer/question to look at the markup and then just cancel/discard.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$. What do you know about the determinants of upper/lower triangular matrices?

Comment: Good answer... unfortunately I didn't know what the determinants of upper/lower triangular matrices were... My teacher has a strong accent and the book is terrible. Easy to miss something important like that...

Comment: Do you know any of the general rules for computing determinants? Any of them would be easy to apply here to find out the determinant of an upper/lower triangular matrix.

Comment: I know how to find the determinant of 2x2 and larger square matrices, det(-A)=det(A), det(aA)=a^n*det(A), and det(AB)=det(A)det(B). Beyond that... not so much.